# How to query axis limits in R?

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to get the axis limits for the current plot in R? How?

Preferably in the standard base library (I don't like to use `ggplot` etc., but these solutions are also welcome).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
par("usr")
```

That ought to do it; see `?par`.

Comment: Thanks! I had been looking at ?par, but I searched for xlim or something with leading x so I overlooked it. Thanks!

Comment: @TMS `?par` could really go for a makeover, it's a real tome of a help page.

Comment: What about log-axes?

Comment: Log values are returned.