# Is it possible to query the the axis limits before the plot is drawn?

Tags: r, plot

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428594/how-to-query-axis-limits-in-r) but the solution given is insufficient for my use case.

I want zero-base a graph, while preserving the original (automatically generated) upper `ylim`, without drawing and then redrawing the graph.

Here is what I have tried, which does not work because `par` seems to only provide the upperbound on the plot **after the plot has already been drawn**.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript


args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
data <- read.csv(args[1],head=F)
pdf(paste(args[1], ".pdf", sep=''))
plot(seq(1,dim(data)[1]), data$V1, ylim=c(0,par('usr')[4]))
dev.off()
```

Here is some sample data to run this on.

```
117
190
189
189
189
191
192
193
194
197
```

**How might I zero-base my graph while preserving the original upper y limits?**

Comment: Knowing where tick marks will be placed is complicated by fact that other parameters to `plot()` and not just the data can determine where they would go. It's probably best to use something like `ylim=c(0, max(pretty(data$V1)))` to get a reasonable top tick mark.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the default setting `yaxs = "r"`, then you can calculate the upper limit using the information about how the y-limits are calculated from the `xaxs` section (`yaxs` refers you to the `xaxs` section) on the `par` help page:

> xaxs
>   The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis.
>   Possible values are "r", "i", "e", "s", "d". The styles are generally
>   controlled by the range of data or xlim, if given.
>   Style "r" (regular)
>   first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and then finds
>   an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range.

```
upper_lim <- diff(range(x)) * 0.04 + max(x)
upper_lim
#[1] 200.2
```

We can see that this is the value of the upper limit (under default settings) by plotting and then asking about it:

```
plot(seq_along(x$V1), x$V1)
par("usr", no.readonly = TRUE)[4]
# [1] 200.2


plot(seq_along(x$V1), x$V1, ylim = c(0, upper_lim))
```

## data

```
x <- read.table(text = "117
190
189
189
189
191
192
193
194
197")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Possible. There's a parameter that lets `plot` do all the setup but suppresses plotting.  You can then get all the coordinates with par("usr"). It was `type = "n"` documented in `?plot`. The plotting code would then be:

```
Y <- scan(text="117
190
189
189
189
191
192
193
194
197")
plot(seq(1,length(Y)), Y, type="n") # plots to the interactive device

 opar=par()

pdf( "Y.pdf"); # needed to get the 'usr' value  before resetting `par` with new device
   plot(seq(1,10),Y, ylim=c(0,opar$usr[4]))
dev.off()

par(opar)
```

Comment: I looked around and was not able to find such a parameter documented anywhere. If you happen to remember it, please update this answer.